# Python does not warn about variable re-declaration

Tags: python

I just spent a whole day tracking down this bug:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(some_list):
    for idx, otherval in enumerate(another_list): #the idx for the outer loop is overwritten
        #blah blah
```

Coming from a strongly typed language background, I got bitten hard by this. In strongly typed languages I would get an error about variable re-declaration. I don't know why the interpreter doesn't issue a warning for this, and the design decision behind this. This is obviously a bug, I mean, what could possibly be the legit use of this construct? Is there any option to enable this sort of check? Thanks.

Comment: Python variables are "declared" implicitly by their first use: `idx = 1` then later, `idx = 2` would trigger the same warning.

Comment: C#: `int i; for (i=1; i<10;i++) { for (i=20; i<30; i++) { /* blah blah */ } }` - no warning.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yeah, but would it be more common that `for(int i= 0; i < 10; i ++){for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++){....}}` Then the compiler would catch that

Comment: @Blorgbeard that's an excellent reason to always use `for (int i...` instead of `int i; for (i...`.

Comment: The C# code I wrote is closest to your python code, because it's not redeclaring the variable - just reusing it. Obv. in C#, you would not do this. But it's how python works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to enable this sort of check. Ordinarily I'd recommend using a linting tool, but `pylint` (my favorite) doesn't seem to notice this, and neither does `pychecker`.

As for rationale: you want to allow stuff like

```
a = 1
a = 2
```

Ok, so how about

```
a = ""
a = 1
```

Well that should probably be ok too. Now what about

```
a = 1
for a in range(5):
```

You see the problem? It's not really that clear what should be an error/warning and what shouldn't.

(I admit I would like this thing to be caught by a tool like `pychecker`, and I'm a little disappointed.)

Answer (score 2):

This is how Python works, you are free to redefine variables. If you expect it to behave like a statically typed language, you're only in for disappointment.